# New Xming Windows Doesn't Grab Focus

Tags: cygwin, x-windows, xming

I do my day-to-day work on Windows 7 (no, that's not going to change) and often need to work with Linux running on Parallels. Switching between Windows and Linux desktops is a pain, so I've installed Cygwin+Xming (less complicated than CygwinX). I open a Cygwin command line using mintty, then do ssh -Y to get a Linux command line. Doing "vim" on the Linux command line causes the vim window to appear on my Windows desktop.

This is great, except that the new vim window doesn't automatically grab the focus, which stays with the mintty window. Years of habit cause me to start typing immediately without clicking on the new window. Having to switch manually is very jarring. Any way to make it automatic?

Comment: Sounds like a Xming problem, doubt if there is any solution to it, try a bug report for them to fix.

Comment: Even if xming is stupid about focus, there ought to be some X command for directing the focus to a specific window.

Comment: Is it just VIM that doesn't get focus, or other things? There is a cygwin mailing list. cygwin-subscribe@cygwin.com  you may need subject "subscribe"  And if you scroll down to the bottom of this page http://cygwin.com/lists.html  there's an option to choose a cygwin related mailing list and subscribe to it.

Comment: @barlop - it's not realted to cygwin at all, it's purely Xming issue.

Comment: Five years, and no answer. FWIW, this is still a problem.

Comment: Still a problem in 2020. With home-office during Corona, on a larger scale than ever.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Xming X server, you may also connect via [Putty](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html) and focus will be directed to the vim window.

I use that on Windows to open Emacs.